# How to trace a path generated by openCV findContours() using ReportLab PDFgen?

Tags: python, opencv, pdf-generation

Im working with openCV for a project that traces patterns and allows me to manipulate that pattern as a path in Adobe Illustrator with the image of the pattern in the background.

Below is the solution that I and a friend have come up with.

The output of drawContours() doesn't match the vector path I am creating with PDFgen.

drawContours() output has a blue stroke

generated path has black stroke

My source code is below.

How can I trace a path generated by findContours() using ReportLab PDFgen?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

print(cv2.__version__)

im = cv2.imread('img.jpg')

#Orient the image properly

# grab the dimensions of the image and calculate the center
# of the image
(h, w) = im.shape[:2]
center = (w / 2, h / 2)

# rotate the image by 180 degrees
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, 180, 1.0)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(im, M, (w, h))

#flip the image across
flippedColor = cv2.flip(rotated, 1) #used to display the result of drawContours in color

imgray = cv2.cvtColor(rotated, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.flip(imgray, 1)

#thresholding
(thresh, binRed) = cv2.threshold(blur, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

_, Rcontours, hier_r = cv2.findContours(binRed,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
r_areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in Rcontours]
max_rarea = np.argmax(r_areas)
CntExternalMask = np.ones(binRed.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255

contourMax= Rcontours[max_rarea]

# calc arclentgh
arclen = cv2.arcLength(contourMax, True)

# approx the contour
epsilon = arclen * 0.0005
contour = cv2.approxPolyDP(contourMax, epsilon, True)

cv2.drawContours(flippedColor,[contour],-1,(255,0,0),1)

'''
#display the image for testing
cv2.imshow('image',flippedColor)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
'''

#set up the pdf with proper size and stuff 
canvas = canvas.Canvas("output.pdf", pagesize=letter)
canvas.bottomup = 1
canvas.setLineWidth(0.1)
h,w = im.shape[:2]
canvas.setPageSize((h, w))
canvas.drawImage("img.jpg", 0, 0)

#draw the path
last_angle = 0
last_angle1 = 0
p1 = contour[0][0]
ccount = 0

pathman = canvas.beginPath()

for index,p in enumerate(contour):
      if index==len(contour)-1:
        break
      s1 = contour[index+1][0]
      p = p[0]
      dist1 =  get_dist(p1,p)
      dist2 =  get_dist(s1,p)
      dist = get_dist(s1,p1)

      ccount+=1
      cv2.circle(CntExternalMask, (p[0], p[1]), 5, (0,255,0), -1)
      cv2.circle(CntExternalMask, (p1[0], p1[1]), 5, (0,255,0), -1)
      cv2.line(CntExternalMask, (p[0], p[1]), (p1[0], p1[1]), (100, 200, 0), 5)
      pathman.moveTo(p[0],p[1])
      pathman.lineTo(p[0],p[1])
      canvas.line(p[0], p[1],p1[0], p1[1])
      p1 = p

p = contour[0][0]

cv2.line(CntExternalMask, (p[0], p[1]), (p1[0], p1[1]), (100, 200, 0), 5)
print ("count = ",ccount)
canvas.line(p[0], p[1],p1[0], p1[1])
canvas.drawPath(pathman, fill=1, stroke=1)

canvas.save()    

#save image
cv2.imwrite("output.jpg", CntExternalMask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

[image]